# Drawing minarea rectangle for convex hull

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi i've been trying to recognize hand signatures(numbers) using OpenCV.i am encountering a problem where 1 and 2 show the same number of convexity defects.
One way i thought i could rectify this was by drawing a Minbounding rectangle..and find the ratio of the area of the convex hull to that of the bounding rectangle.
However im not aware how to do this.

```
vector<vector<Point>> hull;
```

The index of the hull i am interested in is say k;

How do i draw a rotated rectangle for this convex hull?

Comment: The function returns the points of a minimum area rectangle..so i declare a vector of points..vector<Point> minimumarearec..and then..

Comment: look [here](http://simena86.github.io/blog/2013/08/12/hand-tracking-and-recognition-with-opencv/)

Comment: [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) you can find an example on how to use and draw RotatedRects

Comment: You should post well defined question, as "How to draw a RotatedRect in OpenCV", and post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not your entire code.

Comment: Edited the title and body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assuming 
// vector<vector<Point>> hull;
// Mat3b frame; 

if((k >= 0) && (k < hull.size()) && (!hull[k].empty()))
{
    RotatedRect rotated = minAreaRect(hull[k]);
    Point2f rect_points[4]; 
    rotated.points( rect_points );
    for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
       line( frame, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j+1)%4], Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8 );
    }
}
```